# Overflow-x: scroll !important not working on Samsung Internet with translated SVG's

Tags: android, css, svg, overflow, samsung-internet

I have a `div` container horizontally filled up with a set of SVG drawings which are drawn dynamically. Because the width of the container exceeds the window's width an `overflow-x: scroll !important` is applied. However, even though it works in most of the browsers, the Samsung Internet browser won't make the `div` scrollable. Is there anything I can do about it?

EDIT: jQuery's `scroll()` function won't fire an `alert` event either

EDIT2: I perform a dynamic `translate()` on each SVG drawing to arrange them into a grid layout

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: @SeyyedMojtabaAkramzade I found a solution to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason for this issue:

As I said I am drawing the SVG elements dynamically. I also `transform: translate()` them. But this won't make the `overflow-x` working on Samsung Internet. Instead, I had to create a wrapper `div` for each svg drawing and translate this wrapper rather than the svg itself.

So instead of this structure:

```
<div id="big-wrapper">
  <svg style="transform: translate([dynamic value to order all svgs in a grid])"></svg>
  <svg style="transform: translate([dynamic value to order all svgs in a grid])"></svg>
  <svg style="transform: translate([dynamic value to order all svgs in a grid])"></svg>
  ...
</div>
```

I need this structure:

```
<div id="big-wrapper">
  <div id="small-wrapper1" style="transform: translate([dynamic value to order all svgs in a grid])">
     <svg></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="small-wrapper2" style="transform: translate([dynamic value to order all svgs in a grid])">
     <svg></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="small-wrapper3" style="transform: translate([dynamic value to order all svgs in a grid])">
     <svg></svg>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```